# Find all n-th purchases and return a sum of them by category

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table of purchases containing:
id | time | user_id (to table with users) | product_id (to table with products. I am looking for all n-th purchases by certain users (in my case - 3rd)? for example:
purchases                     I will have to give answer as:

```
| 1 | foo_time | 1 | 2 |      | user_city      | sum_of_3-rd_purchases | 
| 2 | foo_time | 1 | 2 |      | city_of_user_1 | value_of_product_5    |
| 3 | foo_time | 1 | 5 |      | city_of_user_2 | value_of_product_3    |
| 4 | foo_time | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | foo_time | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | foo_time | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | foo_time | 2 | 4 |
| 8 | foo_time | 3 | 4 |
```

I only struggle with finding exactly 3-rd purchases in table (which is originally not sorted btw).
What should I do? (All information about user's city and prices of products are given in users and products tables)

Comment: The question will be clearer with example datasets and expected result. So, can you mock up the user and products table. And also show what the expected result should be for that mocked up dataset.

Comment: user: | id | time_of_creation | city | ----         
product : | id | price | ----
Looks like that

Comment: Comments don't give a good representation of mocked tables, so: if the city of user 1 is Paris, the city of User 2 is New-York and the prices of products 5 and 3 are 100 and 200 dollars, the resulting table would look like: ---- | Paris | 100| ; --- | New-york | 200 |. ----
If there were more than 1 user with >=3 purchases from New-york (e.g), the price of his 3-rd purchase should be added up to the value in New-York row.

Comment: `row_number() over (partition by user_id order by time) % 3 = 0`. You'll need to return the result somewhere and the filter as a separate step unless `qualify` is available.